# How to upload multiple image with 2 size using php class.upload.php?

Tags: php

I am using following php script to upload image.

https://github.com/verot/class.upload.php/blob/master/README.md

Well, Now I want to upload multiple images with 2 **sizes**. One is **large** and other is **small**.

So, to get this result, I am using following code but it's not saving this **small** image-> `$handle->file_new_name_body = 'mpic_thumb'.uniqid('', true);`

**php code :**

```
foreach ($files as $file) {

    $handle = new upload($file);

    if ($handle->uploaded) {

        $handle->file_new_name_body = 'mpic_'.uniqid('', true);
        $handle->image_resize          = true;
        $handle->image_ratio_fill      = true;
        $handle->image_x               = 360;
        $handle->image_y               = 240;                 


        $handle->file_new_name_body = 'mpic_thumb'.uniqid('', true);
        $handle->image_resize          = true;
        $handle->image_ratio_fill      = true;  
        $handle->image_x               = 100;
        $handle->image_y               = 65;

        $handle->process('images/menu_images/');
        if ($handle->processed) {
            echo 'image thumb resized';
            $handle->clean();
        } else {
            echo 'error : ' . $handle->error;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Oh, It' working now. I have to call `$handle->process('images/menu_images/');` after first properties :)

Comment: instead of doing this way, try to create 2 separate function, one for thumbnail, and one for normal image. Also there might be an issue that image is small in size than that dimension

Comment: yes exactly that was what I was trying to say @shibbir ahmed

Comment: Feel free to up-vote/accept if it helped anyhow or you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Use the both functions separately like this, and process them separately :

```
foreach ($files as $file) {

  $handle = new upload($file);

  if ($handle->uploaded) {

    $handle->file_new_name_body = 'mpic_'.uniqid('', true);
    $handle->image_resize          = true;
    $handle->image_ratio_fill      = true;
    $handle->image_x               = 360;
    $handle->image_y               = 240;                 
    $handle->process('images/menu_images/');
    if ($handle->processed) {
        echo 'image thumb resized';
        $handle->clean();
    } else {
        echo 'error : ' . $handle->error;
    }

    $handle->file_new_name_body = 'mpic_thumb'.uniqid('', true);
    $handle->image_resize          = true;
    $handle->image_ratio_fill      = true;  
    $handle->image_x               = 100;
    $handle->image_y               = 65;

    $handle->process('images/menu_images/');
    if ($handle->processed) {
        echo 'image thumb resized';
        $handle->clean();
    } else {
        echo 'error : ' . $handle->error;
    }
  }   
}
```

Also the other way is call `$handle->process('images/menu_images/');` after both images function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do them seperately. You are effectively overwriting the settings. Try something like this

```
foreach ($files as $file) {

$handle = new upload($file);

if ($handle->uploaded) {

    $handle->file_new_name_body = 'mpic_'.uniqid('', true);
    $handle->image_resize          = true;
    $handle->image_ratio_fill      = true;
    $handle->image_x               = 360;
    $handle->image_y               = 240;                 
    $handle->process('images/menu_images/');
    if ($handle->processed) {
        echo 'image thumb resized';
        $handle->clean();
    } else {
        echo 'error : ' . $handle->error;
    }

    $handle->file_new_name_body = 'mpic_thumb'.uniqid('', true);
    $handle->image_resize          = true;
    $handle->image_ratio_fill      = true;  
    $handle->image_x               = 100;
    $handle->image_y               = 65;

    $handle->process('images/menu_images/');
    if ($handle->processed) {
        echo 'image thumb resized';
        $handle->clean();
    } else {
        echo 'error : ' . $handle->error;
    }
}   
}
```